Symfony form: how to set dynamic choices based on other attribute of entity?
I have a form type
class ArticleTranslationType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder
            ->add('locale', ChoiceType::class, [
                'choices' => $this->getLocales($builder), // need to implement
            ];
    }

    // ...
}

I need to implement method getLocales. It is dynamic list that depends on other translation. If translation already exists for the other sibling, it should not be in this list
In controller I builds it this way

class ArticleController extends AbstractController
{
    public function update(Request $request): Response
    {
        // ...
        //getting article and translation from EM

        $form = $this->createFormBuilder([
            'article' => $article,
            'translation' => $translation,
        ])
        ->add('article', ArticleType::class)
        ->add('translation', ArticleTranslationType::class)
        ->getForm();
    }
    // ...
}

How to make choices dynamic?

I found the solution. In the bottom of the buildForm method I added
class ArticleTranslationType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        //...
        $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, $this->buildLocale(...));
    }

    private function buildLocale(FormEvent $event): void
    {
        $event->getForm()
            ->add('locale', ChoiceType::class, [
                'choices' => $this->getAvailableLocales($event->getData()),
                'label' => $this->translator->trans('Locale', [], 'article'),
                'attr' => [
                    'class' => 'form-select',
                ],
                'constraints' => [
                    new UniqueTranslation()
                ],
            ]);
    }

    /**
     * @param ArticleTranslation $articleTranslation
     * @return array<string, string>
     */
    public function getAvailableLocales(ArticleTranslation $articleTranslation): array
    {
        $availableLocales = array_flip($this->language->buildLanguages());
        $translations = $articleTranslation->getArticle()->getArticleTranslations();
        foreach ($translations as $translation) {
            if ($translation->getId() != $articleTranslation->getId() && isset($availableLocales[$translation->getLocale()])) {
                unset($availableLocales[$translation->getLocale()]);
            }
        }

        return array_flip($availableLocales);
    }

